# View color specific to touch point

Tags: android

I wanna make a bar which changes to a different colour until the point where it is touched. Like this:

[image: Click here to view an image of what I'm trying to say]

Comment: SE isn't suited for "I need this, give me the full code", you need to be specific. Will the bar always be orange up to where you tap or does the color change? What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? etc

Comment: I have no idea where to start with this. And the bar will stay orange until the bar is touched at some other point it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A seek bar](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/seekbar) will probably suit your needs very well, since you can customize the bar color, the bar itself and the progress indicator.

If you want it vertical you can probably use `setRotation()` (even though I'm not sure since I never actually used it I don't see why it wouldn't work).

Comment: The rotation does work. And thanks for the answer worked like a charm.